# Can .htaccess rewrites request files outside of the htdocs/httpsdocs area of a server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my server, a website resides within a directory similar to `/domains/domain.com/public_html`. I wish to keep the domain at this path, as all the main files are there, but is there any way to source *some* files from another location in my server, eg. `/global/script.js`?

In short, I hope to write a *mod-rewrite* than can source specific files from outside the **DocumentRoot**, or something very similar, but I cannot work out a solution.

I figure I could manage this by directing **all** files to a PHP script (css, js, php, images, etc), which will then work out what file is requested, load the files contents and return it with the correct header. I feel this will more than likely slow down all requests because I believe this requires more processes, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for mod_rewrite: If all files are in the same directory, you can use alias.

```
Alias /MyMapDir /global/resources
```

a request to `example.com/MyMapDir/script.js` will be mapped to `/global/resources/script.js`

Note that this works in httpd.conf only!

Comment: Thank you I will give the Alias a shot, but I fear my live server may not allow this (I know I can play with it in my local WAMP though)

Comment: @Rhys as far as I know, there is no way of doing this if you don't have access to the server configuration. Everything possible in `.htaccess` files seems to be limited to the `VirtualHost` in question but can't point beyond. An alternative may be creating symbolic links that point to the global directory